# Count number of preceding zeroes based on last occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Python (multiple rows by product store and week combination (sorted)).

```
product store week visit prob
123     321   1    0     0.003
123     321   2    0     0.234
123     321   3    1     0
123     321   4    0     0.198
123     301   1    0     0.290
123     301   2    2     0
123     301   3    0     0.989
123     301   4    4     0.788
```

I want to find the cumulative probability multiplied based on the number of preceding zeroes in the visit column. For example: for each product store week combination, I will find the first occurrence of visits>0. Then count the number of preceding zeroes. And then multiply by all the rows in the **prob** column until I hit a value>0 and the last week for that product store combination. Something like below. For visits > 0 the cum_prob can be left blank or with 0.

```
product store week visit prob   cum_prob
123     321   1    0     0.003  0.000702
123     321   2    0     0.234  0.000702
123     321   3    1     0
123     321   4    0     0.198  0.198
123     301   1    0     0.290  0.290
123     301   2    2     0
123     301   3    0     0.989  0.989
123     301   4    4     0.788
```

How can I achieve this in Python? In SAS I could have used arrays and some loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll create a working data set `d1` and assign some new columns to it.

- `iszero` tracks where `prob` is zero.  I'll multiply by this column later
- `novist` tracks where we `visit` is not zero.  I'll multiply by this later and use it to help create groups
- `filled_prob` fills in `1` where `prob` was zero.  This facilitates in making my `prod` function later work well.

---

```
d1 = df.assign(
    iszero=df.prob.eq(0),
    novisit=df.visit.ne(0),
    filled_prob=np.where(df.prob.eq(0), 1, df.prob)
)

d1
```

[image]

I'll use one of the columns I just created to create a grouping column

```
d1['visit_group'] = d1.groupby(['product', 'store']).novisit.cumsum()
d1
```

[image]

Finally, add `'cum_prob'` with the columns I produced above.

```
d1['cum_prob'] = d1.groupby(
    ['product', 'store', 'visit_group']
).filled_prob.transform('prod') * (~d1.iszero) * (~d1.novisit)
d1
```

[image]

---

You can slice it for your purposes

```
d1.loc[:, df.columns.tolist() + ['cum_prob']]
```

[image]

---

***all together***

```
d1 = df.assign(
    iszero=df.prob.eq(0),
    novisit=df.visit.ne(0),
    filled_prob=np.where(df.prob.eq(0), 1, df.prob)
)
d1['visit_group'] = d1.groupby(['product', 'store']).novisit.cumsum()
d1['cum_prob'] = d1.groupby(
    ['product', 'store', 'visit_group']
).filled_prob.transform('prod') * (~d1.iszero) * (~d1.novisit)
d1.loc[:, df.columns.tolist() + ['cum_prob']]
```

---

Response to comment:

whether weeks skip doesn't change the calculation as I've laid out.  Instead, we can pre-filter `df` like this

```
def skip_weeks(x):
    """check if difference in week from one row
    to the next is always 1.  If not, then we skipped a week"""
    return x.week.diff().dropna().eq(1).all()

# I'll use this to map and filter in a bit
no_skips = df.groupby(['product', 'store']).apply(skip_weeks)

# produces
# product  store
# 123      301      True
#          321      True
# dtype: bool

# simple series of tuples
# could've done `df[['product', 'store']].apply(tuple, 1)`
# but this is quicker
s = pd.Series(list(zip(df['product'].tolist(), df.store.tolist())), df.index)

# filter, this is what we then use rest of algorithm on
# remember to assign it to a variable like `df = df.loc[s.map(no_skips)]`
df.loc[s.map(no_skips)]
```

Comment: Much appreciated , can you also explain the 2nd last step. Transform part

Comment: [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) returns an object with the same index passed to the `groupby` replicating values within groups.

Comment: I really don't like this answer. Very convoluted and hard to follow.

Comment: @TedPetrou I've updated my answer.  Hopefully you find it more palatable.

Comment: this seemed to have worked but where are we taking into account the week? for example if for row 6 week was 4 instead of 3 and for row 7 week was 5, which means week =3 was missing. then the cum prob should be calculated in a different way. Ideally i would want to skip the rows in calculating for cum_prob for any week that is missng from data

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will assign each week into a group and then find the cumulative sum based on that group.

The first thing that is done is turn visits into 0/1 with `s.ne(0)`. Then the first difference which will create -1/1 for the first row in a group. The cumulative sum of the absolute value is then taken on this to create the groups. Then we can simply use `transform` and take the product of each group.

```
df['group'] = df.groupby(['product', 'store'])['visit']\
                .transform(lambda s: s.ne(0).diff().abs().cumsum().fillna(0))

df['cum_prod'] = df.groupby(['product', 'store', 'group'])['prob']\
                   .transform(lambda s: s.prod())
```

See the group column in the output below. The one thing you would have to do is make all the non-zero visits have 0 probability, which the last row does not do.

```
   product  store  week  visit   prob  group  cum_prod
0      123    321     1      0  0.003      0  0.000702
1      123    321     2      0  0.234      0  0.000702
2      123    321     3      1  0.000      1  0.000000
3      123    321     4      0  0.198      2  0.198000
4      123    301     1      0  0.290      0  0.290000
5      123    301     2      2  0.000      1  0.000000
6      123    301     3      0  0.989      2  0.989000
7      123    301     4      4  0.788      3  0.788000
```

Comment: `df.loc[7, 'cum_prod']` should be zero.. i believe